# escape backslash in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

How can I make this "/\" show up in my interpreter tree?

```
expression
    :   boolean_expression (('/\'' | '\'/') boolean_expression)* 
    ;
```

I already managed to fix \/ by putting '\'/' as you can see. and it prints \/
but /\ wont work.

Before you ask, this is a project and I must use these notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
   expression
        :   boolean_expression ((UP | DOWN) boolean_expression)* 
        ;

    boolean_expression
        :   'true' | 'false'

        ;


    UP  :    '/''\\'    ;


    DOWN    :   '\\''/';
```